# Discord: Using a command to get Data from Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, discord.js

I have been trying to look through so many different types of tutorial for this but nothing I do seems to be working. For my discord bot I created a json file that houses the following object

```
{"trainer":[{"name":"Bob","C0":45,"C1":84,"C2":147},
    {"name":"Paul","C0":60,"C1":104,"C2":167}],
"prefix":!
}
```

Now I am trying to figure out how I can make a command so if someone types in !trainer Bob I want the bot display the values for CO, C1, and C2

At the moment I have the following:

```
const args = message.content.slice(X.prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

X is the name of the json file. the following is where I get stuck

```
 if(command === "trainer"){
    message.channel.send('WHAT DO I PUT HERE?')
}
```

Now I am very new to this all, but if my understanding is correct, my argument 0 is trainer in this case, so what I would like is to use my first argument (which would be the name after !trainer) to link back to the array in my json file so that I can get the other values in the array. Now what I am thinking of doing is creating a const with Shift(1) so that const holds my first argument, but I am still not sure how to use that to get the information from the array. Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the available trainers in your json data based on the user's first argument which should be the trainer's name. If a name in the json data matches the user’s requested trainer, you can make use of a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to cleanly construct a string to send, else you can tell the user that the trainer doesn't exist.

```
let queriedTrainerName = args[0];
let trainersArray = X.trainer;
let matchingTrainers = trainersArray.filter(trainerObject => trainerObject.name.toLowerCase() === queriedTrainerName.toLowerCase());
if (matchingTrainers.length > 0) {
    let firstMatch = matchingTrainers[0];
    message.channel.send(`For trainer ${queriedTrainerName}: C0 is ${firstMatch.C0}, C1 is ${firstMatch.C1}, C2 is ${firstMatch.C2}`);
} else message.channel.send(`Trainer ${queriedTrainerName} does not exist!`);
```